# Providence Pentominoes Puzzle By Andrew Bradburn (Jigsaw)

Tags: cryptic-crosswords, unsolved-mysteries

I came across this apparently well known cryptic crossword with a twist but was unable to solve it. I also haven't been able to find a solution anywhere online so I was wondering if anyone here could help me finish it.
Thanks in advance.

So my question is, can anyone solve this for me and explain the bits I was unable to figure out.

[Link to download it.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sy0ph672nej2f8w/Providence_Pentominoes_Puzzle_Bradburn.pdf?dl=0)

My attempt so far are in the spoiler boxes if you want to try it with or without using my partial solution.

**My grid - not fully correct**

> ```
>   *???ER?*
>   PURITANS
>   LYDIAN??
>   A?SUFISM
>   GRISLYS?
>   UONAORTA
>   EFFLUVIA
>   *LOFRHP*
> ```

**My answers with my explanations:**

> **Across**
>  1. ??? - no idea
>  6. PURITANS - anagram of "aunt rips". Fits definition.
>  8. LYDIA - hidden in "sparkLY DIAmond" Fits definition.
>  9. SUFISM - end (ultimately) of belieF IS in SUM (total). Fits definition.
>  11. GRISLY - double meaning - bear & horror. Not sure what 'Reportedly' means here.
>  15. AORTA - two (articles) A around half of impORT. The heart is a vessel.
>  16. EFFLUVIA - (backed up iron) EF chimney (FLU) then not really sure on end part. Maybe answer is EFFLUENT but it fitted worse.
>  17. first letters of (initially) Reaches Home Plate
>
>  **Down**
>  1. ??? - not sure.
>  2. FICUS - ficus benjamin is a species of tree, bejamin=$100. Not completely sure this answer is right.
>  3. ETA - dined is ATE reversed (wrong way)
>  4. RANI - anagram of IRAN. Not completely sure of this one.
>  5. ??? - no clue.
>  6. PLAGUE - capital of Czech PRAGUE with L replaced with R
>  7. ??? - not idea. Something with SA in.
>  10. FLOUR - FOUR (beatles number) with meaning of Last. 'Meal' is a synonym of Flour.
>  12. ROFL - hidden in useR OF Linux.
>  13. INFO - IN backwards (back) OF. 'Skinny' is synonym of information.
>  14. STEP - STEPHEN (composer Sondheim) minus HEN (fowl). 'Step' is a type of 'Measure'.
>  15. ALF - Double definition: Alf Landon & Alf the 80's sitcom.

Problems/Issues with my answers

> FICUS and LYDIA don't fit together right. STEP & EFFLUVIA don't find together right. I know one such thing is allowed and a [passing comment discussing this puzzle and many others](https://tmcaylifeasapuzzle.wordpress.com/2015/08/31/jaw-dropping-puzzles/) makes me believe that FICUS/LYDIA is right and makes a ¢ symbol which fits.
>  Also fitting the words I have done into a [3x20 grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino#/media/File:Pentomino_Puzzle_Solutions.svg) doesn't give me a partial message.

Comment: So what's the actual question here? I'm not quite sure what you're asking -- do you just want the solution?

Comment: Yes. I'm just after a solution with explanation. Sorry, I'll make that explicit in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finished grid is:

> [image]

Rearranged, this becomes:

> [image]
>  where you can see "CAPITAL OF RHODE ISLAND" reading across the bottom.

---

The clues you're missing:

1A:

> Head of Google = G, provided = IF, file format = **GIF**

11A:

> bear = GRIZZLY, "reportedly" is a homophone indicator, making "horror" (**GRISLY**)

16A:

> "Backed-up iron" = EF, chimneys trapping unknown = FLU(X)ES, outflows = **EFFLUXES**

1D:

> "Appearence" = GUISE, "speaking" is a homophone indicator, making **GUYS** ("men's")

2D:

> Loud = F (as in musical notation), one = I, American = US, "hiding" C: this makes **FICUS**

5D:

> "Repairs" = MENDS; "first off", that is **ENDS**, which is "remnants"

7D:

> "What Wharton confers" = MBAS (as in the degrees). After S.A., this makes **SAMBAS**.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the explanation on those. A few of those I hadn't seen before. Also I had the wrong arrangement of the 3x20 which wasn't letting me get all the final message - I had "f Rhode Isl" but the rest didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

1 down:

> GUYS (defn: men's, sounds like guise=appearance)

7 down:

> SAMBAS, multiple Samba(dance), SA+MBA's (from [Wharton School](https://www.wharton.upenn.edu/))

14 down:

> STEP (stepHEN (fowl) [Sondheim)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Sondheim)

16 across:

> EFFLUVES (multiple [EFFLUVE](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effluve)=outflow,v EF+FLU+_+ES (chimneys=FLUES, unknown (as in variable? = V)

New Grid:

> ```
>   *G??ER?*
>   PURITANS
>   LYDIAN?A
>   ASSUFISM
>   GRISLYSB
>   UONAORTA
>   EFFLUVES
>   *LOFRHP*
> ```